# Как использовать спринг-бины в expressions в Activiti (ServiceTask)?

Tags: java, alfresco

Не получается использовать бины в выражения в Activiti (в ServiceTask). Он пишет, что не видит этот бин.
Выдержка из пом по версиям:

```
<springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springframework.boot>2.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.boot>
        <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
```

Бины определяю аннотациями над классами.
Выдержка из файла bpmn-схемы:

```
<serviceTask id="SendStatus104" name="Формирование и отправка статуса" activiti:expression="${sendService.sendStatusCode(104)}">
  <documentation>Формирование и отправка статуса</documentation>
</serviceTask>
```

Объявление класса:

```
    @Service("sendService")
public class SendServiceImpl implements SendService {
//some code
}
```

Comment: Возможно, ваши классы SendServiceImpl находятся за пределами сканирования DI контейнером. Нужно в xml файл конфигурации добавить scan path с местоположением данных классов

Comment: @ArchDemon не знаю, используют спринг-бут 2-ой версии и активити 6-ой. Мне кажется, xml-конфиг только для старых версий. Предполагаю, что в новых уже при создании бина можно указать нужные настройки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать другие классы для создания бинов конфигурации Активити:

```
@Bean
SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration(@Qualifier("dataSourceForActiviti") DataSource dataSourceForActiviti,
                                                            @Qualifier("transactionManagerForActiviti") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerForActiviti) {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
    processEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(transactionManagerForActiviti);

    processEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSourceForActiviti)
            .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
            .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
    ;

    processEngineConfiguration.setDeploymentResources(new Resource[]{
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/1LicensingProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/2ReissuanceLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/3IssueOfDuplicateProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/4IssuanceOfCopyProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/5TerminationOfLicenseProcess.bpmn20.xml"),
            new ClassPathResource("bpm/RLic6ExtractFromRegisterOfLicensesProcess.bpmn20.xml")
    });


    return processEngineConfiguration;
}

@Bean
ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration) {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    processEngineFactoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration);
    return processEngineFactoryBean;
}
```

Для создания объектов сервисов Активити нужно делать так (на примере сервиса `RepositoryService`):

```
@Bean
RepositoryService repositoryService(ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngineFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    return processEngineFactoryBean.getObject().getRepositoryService();
}
```